# Unable to enter <car> on <country> Contest Server

Tags: code-rally

After struggluling to login (had to create 3 users until it worked), now I'm unnable to enter races, and I have no clue why.

I'm using Windows 8.1, x64 and an Intermediate AI (simply followed the tutorial [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/code-rally/entry/zero_to_racing_in_60_seconds))

Error:

[image: error]

Server config:

[image: server config]

---

**EDIT**: Removing servers.json from `C:\Users\<user>\user\.coderally` did NOT worked. /:
Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the Brazil server logs it looks like your id has not been set right when logging in. You can fix this either by logging out and logging in again in the Eclipse UI (your username above is fine to continue using). If that does not work then you will need to delete your local game settings. Close Eclipse then go to your user folder, find a folder called "user" (inside your user folder) and inside that you should find ".coderally" (note this folder may be hidden by default on windows so you'll need to tell windows to show hidden folders). In there delete the "servers.json" file. Once you've done that open Eclipse and login again - if that does not work please update this question and we can look at it more.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Unfortunately removing the file didn't worked. I've edited my question, as requested.

Comment: Are you logging in with Twitter? It looks like Twitter login is down for code rally at the moment so that's causing logins to fail.

Comment: No... I'm logging in with Google.

Comment: I've had a look in the user ID database and can see your IDs have been created and seem to be linked to an OAuth login (I can't see which provider or any OAuth info but the login key is there). When you click on login can you confirm that you get asked to login with google and that when you do that you get a login successful message and not a red screen? If you can email me at tom.banks@uk.ibm.com I can email you something we can try to get around this.